# Uneven tiles in the GRID

Tags: html, css

I need help with the tiles I made using GRID. The issue is that the second and third tiles are unevenly positioned in height; they have different heights. The same problem occurs with tiles 4, 5, and 6—they are also unevenly positioned in height relative to their column. What could be the problem?

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCKsv.png)

```
`<div class="box">
      <div class="item">Плитка 1</div>
      <div class="item">Плитка 2</div>
      <div class="item">Плитка 3</div>
      <div class="item">Плитка 4</div>
      <div class="item">Плитка 5</div>
      <div class="item">Плитка 6</div>
    </div>`




`.box {
        width: 750px;
        height: 360px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 44% 32% 24%;
    }

    .item {
      background: #b3b3b3;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    .item:first-child {
      grid-row: 1/6;
    }

    .item:nth-child(2){
      background: #898995;
      grid-row: 1/3;
    }
    .item:nth-child(3) {
      background: #898995;
      grid-row: 3/6;
    }

    .item:nth-child(4){
      grid-row: 1/2;
      background: #7a7a7a;
    }
    .item:nth-child(5){
      grid-row: 2/4;
      background: #7a7a7a;
    }
    .item:nth-child(6) {
      grid-row: 4/6;
      background: #7a7a7a;
    }`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0u4o7ycw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers in `grid-row` count the lines between the rows.  Your first child should be `1/7`, because a column with 6 rows has 7 row lines.  Then, the second column is `1/4` and `4/7`, and the third column is `1/3`, `3/5`, `5/7`.

Comment: My friend, thank you very much! You helped me a lot.